# Borel's Hierarchy of Real numbers

Tags: elementary-set-theory, real-numbers

I'm trying to find the place of the Real numbers with the usual topology in the Borel Hierarchy, $\Delta_{3}^{0}$ is what my intuition says since $\mathbb{Q}$ is $F_{\sigma}$ and $\mathbb{I}$ is $G_{\delta}$, assuming that the union of $\Sigma_{\alpha}^{0}$ and $\Pi_{\alpha}^{0}$ is $\Delta_{\alpha + 1}^{0}$, an argument similar to $\mathbb{Q}\cup\mathbb{I}=\mathbb{R}$ but have no solid proof.

Answer (score 3):

You're over-thinking this. $\mathbb{R}$ is both open and closed, so it is $\Delta^0_1$ (= "clopen"). *(Admittedly, $\mathbb{R}$ is also $\Delta^0_3$ since every $\Delta^0_1$ set is a fortiori $\Delta^0_3$, but it's not "properly" $\Delta^0_3$.)*

In fact, there are exactly two clopen sets; can you find the other one?

> $\emptyset$

Note: above I'm assuming that our "ambient space" is $\mathbb{R}$ (with the usual topology) itself. If for example we're working in $\mathbb{R}^2$ (with the usual topology) instead (and identifying $\mathbb{R}$ with the $x$-axis $\mathbb{R}\times\{0\}\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2$), then $\mathbb{R}$ is closed but *not* open, so properly $\Pi^0_1$. In general you should always specify the ambient space.